# Returning to the activity doesn't load image into imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I have an activity with three `EditText`s. Clicking on any of the `EditText`s shows the same type of dialogue which is basically a list of items.

In this dialogue, I have an `ImageView` that shows a + icon which is a vector drawable file in my drawable folder.

When I first run the activity the image shows up. But, when I move to the next activity and press back to return to the activity with the `EditText` and when I click on the `EditText` the dialogue shows up, but without the plus icon. However, when I am clicking on that portion where the image is supposed to be, it is responding the way as it is supposed to.

MyActivity.java

```
private final View.OnClickListener editTextOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPickerDialogue(some_parameters)
        }

    private void showPickerDialogue(some_parameters){
            PickerDialogue cityPickerDialogue = new PickerDialogue();
            cityPickerDialogue.setAruguments(parameter_in_bundle);
            cityPickerDialogue.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragment_tag);
        }
}
```

PickerDialogue.java

```
public class PickerDialogue extends DialogFragment {

         @Override
         public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
             AlertDialog.Builder dialogueBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

             View dialogueView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                 .inflate(R.layout.dialogue_picker, null);
             dialogueBuilder.setView(dialogueView);
             .
             .
             .
             ImageView imageViewAdd = (ImageView) dialogueView.findViewById(R.id.dialogue_picker_button_add);
             .
             .
             .
             imageViewAdd.setOnClickListener(addNewSchoolListener);
             return dialogueBuilder.create();
         }
}
```

dialogue_picker.xml

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dialogue_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dialogue_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dialogue_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialogue_margin_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogue_picker_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.DialogWindowTitle"
            tools:text="Select city"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialogue_picker_button_add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/dialogue_with_search"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

ic_add.xml (This is the same ic_add icon that comes with Android Studio.)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

Also, the dialogue is basically a list of items using a `ListView`. So when an item on the list is clicked, the item is passed to the `Activity`. It then sets the item to the `EditText`

```
listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                callback.onDialogueItemClick(
                        (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position),
                        editTextId);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Why do you think the image is not showing only when pressing back and returning to the activity?

**Things I have tried**

- Checking with Show Layout Bounds in developer option. It showed that ImageView actually exist, but the image is not getting loaded
- Try loading the image view from Java code instead of XML.
- Changing the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.
- I changed the actual icon with another vector asset. I imported it from New->Vector Asset -> Material icon. This time I used back arrow vector asset and it worked fine. So I imported a new + vector asset and tried but still, it didn't work. I don't know why only + symbol is not working.
- The code is working fine on Xiaomi Redmi 2S Prime running on Android 5.1 The device on which I am facing this problem is Xiaomi Redmi 3S Prime running on Android 6.0

Comment: Try with another image type not SVG, but I can't say that the problem.

Comment: I've recreated your project as much as it's possible, but I cannot see any problem with it: I can click on the `ImageView`, it transfers me to the next activity, and after pressing back I can still see the image I've clicked on. Do you hide your dialog after moving on the next activity? Also your `dialogue_with_search.xml` file is missing from your question; can you show it to us?

Comment: I don't see an SVGs being used here. Perhaps you mean `VectorDrawable`?  Tags updated.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais, I have updated the last point of things I have tried. Please refer

Comment: @Greyson, I have updated my answer. I tested based on Nicolas comment and found out that only + icon is not functioning. Let me know still would you like to see the `dialogue_with_search.xml`?